# Running baker on Docker: how to change settings?

Tags: baker, docker

How can I use the `launch_baker` function changing/adding arguments to the command?

https://gitlab.com/tezos/tezos/blob/master/scripts/docker/entrypoint.inc.sh

Comment: Do you have any specific arguments in mind that you would like to add? You could try to bypass the entrypoint script completely, as suggested by its documentation: "To call the tezos binaries directly you must override the
entrypoint using --entrypoint . All binaries are in
$BIN_DIR and the tezos data in $DATA_DIR" https://gitlab.com/tezos/tezos/blob/master/scripts/docker/entrypoint.sh

Comment: I wanted to change the base-dir and the node data dir.

Comment: To another location inside the docker volume, or to a location on the host?